# Removing null value line in ".dat" file when using PrintWriter

Tags: java, file, null, line, printwriter

Anyone know how to remove null value line in ".dat" file when I create file using `PrintWriter`? 
Why does the file just print a null line in the last page of line, I already put:

```
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(File file));
```

then after I do process ..
 I put:

```
outputFile.flush();
outputFile.close();
```

But null is still printing on the last line. 
When I try to save the file in .txt format, there is no null line. but I need to save as a ".Dat" file.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to call `flush()` immediately before `close()`. From the docs for `close()`: *Close the stream, flushing it first.*

Comment: hi AusCBloke, do you know why null line is printing ? how can I remove it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a null line in a file. At bare minimum it has the newline character (or else its not a line!). Are you talking about the literal text 'null'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suffix doesn't matter for a file, so there should be no difference between these two files. The null value you saw in .Dat file is maybe a place-holder for editor that you opened the file with.